# How to slow down the speed of send_keys action in a selenium script using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I am currently creating a selenium script in python. I need to enter something in a text box using send_keys function. It is doing that correctly as of now. However, for an observation for I need to slow down the speed at which send_keys populates the text field. Is there a way I can do that? Also, is there any alternate to send_keys in selenium?
Thanks&Regards
karan

Answer (score 30):

You could insert a pause after each character is sent. For example, if your code looked like this:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("element-id")
el.send_keys("text to enter")
```

You could replace it with:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("element-id")
text = "text to enter"
for character in text:
    el.send_keys(character)
    time.sleep(0.3) # pause for 0.3 seconds
```

Answer (score 11):

Iterating over Mark's answer, you can wrap it up in a *reusable function*:

```
import time


def slow_type(element, text, delay=0.1):
    """Send a text to an element one character at a time with a delay."""
    for character in text:
        element.send_keys(character)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Version with *type hints*:

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement


def slow_type(element: WebElement, text: str, delay: float=0.1):
    """Send a text to an element one character at a time with a delay."""
    for character in text:
        element.send_keys(character)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

---

Usage:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("element-id")
text = "text to enter"
slow_type(el, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the space and slowing things down fixed the issue

```
def type_and_fill_slow(form_id,message):
    form_id.clear()
    for character in message:
        type(form_id)
        time.sleep(2)
        form_id.send_keys(character)
```

Answer (score 0):

This routine simulates clicking into the field and typing in a little more realistic fashion.

```py
def simulate_typing(
    driver: WebDriver,
    element: WebElement,
    text: str,
    delay: float = 0.1,
):
    actions = ActionChains(driver, duration=20)
    actions.move_to_element(element)
    actions.click(element)
    actions.pause(delay)
    for letter in text:
        actions.send_keys(letter)
        actions.pause(delay)
    actions.perform()
```